# Non-programmatic prevention of SQL injection

Tags: security, sql-injection

I agree that correct input validation is the only 'fool-proof' way to prevent SQL Injection, however it requires modifying a lot of code in existing applications, possibly might require a badly designed application to be re-structured.

There has been a lot of academic interest in automated mechanisms to prevent SQL Injection (won't go on listing them here, I've done a literature survey and seen at least 20), but I haven't seen anything that's actually been implemented.

Does anyone know of any framework that's *actually* in use outside an academic environment, either Signature-Based, Anomaly-Based, or otherwise?

**Edit**: I'm looking for something that **does not** modify the code-base.

Comment: ... Query parametrization?

Comment: Can you name some names/techniques?

Comment: @Ignacio: Query parametrization is a programming technique. I should have specified, I meant something that doesn't require changing the codebase.  @Merlyn: AMNESIA, imPEDE, K. Kemalis and T. Tzouramanis, “Sql-ids: A specification based approach for sql-injection detection”, G. Buehrer, B. W. Weide, and P. A. G. Sivilotti, “Using
parse tree validation to prevent sql injection attacks”...

Comment: How many false positives and false negatives are you going to allow?

Comment: Microsoft has been providing `IIS Lockdown Tool` for about 10 years now.  Among other things it does request filtering looking for suspicious strings.  It also looks for requests using double-escaping, which could pass an input validator and then become malicious after another transformation step.

Answer (score 8):

The company i work for uses [Barracuda Web Application Firewall](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/web-site-firewall-overview.php) for what you are talking about.  From what I have seen it works fairly well.  Basically if it detects suspect input it will redirect the user to a page of our choosing.  This allows you to place a layer between the internet and your applications and does not require you to change any of your code.

That said, it's a bad idea to not secure your applications.

Comment: I know its no replacement for building a secure application, but I would still like to know how effective they are.  Also, how would a firewall protect against Second-Order SQLI?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but I would say yes, unless someone found a way to submit the data in a manner other than the website (daily XML file that gets inserted for instance).  Any suspect data that it detects gets blocked.  Sometimes to a fault.  For instance if someone typed in the name "Mc'Greggor" it would get blocked because of the apostrophe.

Comment: @Vanwaril I don't know about Baracuda in particular, but I know there are [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) products out there that will profile 'known good' behaviour of your application, and then monitor for deviances from this profile. This can prevent SQL Inection, but the correct solution that won't fail is not to permit un-parameterised statements in the first place.

Comment: I feel IDS firewalls don't have enough data to work with to prevent SQL Injection, since the actual injection happens behind the IDS, and its very possible the application takes input from other places.

Comment: @Vanwaril  Barracuda is an **IPS**. Also check out my demo link.  And yes Database firewalls do better to stop sql injection. And a database firewall was just released within the last month.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't going to modify your code then you can only intercept requests. Since there is no such thing as a good or bad SQL command you're pretty limited in options but you could try rejecting multiple queries which initiate from a single string. In other words:

**LEGAL**

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='baz';
```

**ILLEGAL**

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=''; DELETE * FROM foo; SELECT 'baz';
```

Since pretty much every injection attack requires multiple queries in a single request and provided your application doesn't require this feature you may just get away with this. It probably won't catch every type of attack (there's probably a lot of damage you could do using subquerys and functions) but it's probably better than nothing at all.

Comment: That covers only piggybacked queries. there are hundreds of other ways to use SQLI, and a simple regex database of valid queries works better than this.

Comment: did i say it was perfect? it's certainly easier than creating "a simple regex database of valid queries" which is an oxymoron if I ever heard one. the OP already knows he needs to modify his code but chooses not to which only leaves patchwork solutions like this one.

Comment: My point is such 'databases' exist that the OP can directly setup and not touch his code, and it'll be more secure than this. Its not perfect, which is why I asked the question "what's better and used"

Comment: This form of sql injection isn't well supported.  I think sqlite and mssql are the only ones that allow for query stacking.  In MySQL you have to use a special function call for query stacking, and NO ONE USES IT.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to leave the code untouched while patching vulnerabilities like SQL Injection is to use a web application firewall like the open source project [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/).  Recently Oracle has released a [database firewall](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-firewall/index.html) which filters nasty queries.  This approach is better at solving the problem of SQL Injection,  but that all it can address.

WAF's are very useful and free,  if you don't believe it [put it to the test](http://www.modsecurity.org/demo/).

A WAF is just one layer.  You should also [test the application](https://sitewat.ch/About/SQL_Injection)* under it.   This is a defense in depth approach. 

*This is a service I sell with a limited free offer.

Comment: Please do some research before making assertions like "the only way...". That is NOT the only way!

Comment: @Vanwaril What are you talking about?  **A WAF IPS is exactly what you are looking for**.

Comment: @Rook: What's this? It doesn't look like a Firewall to me...  http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~orso/papers/halfond.orso.ASE05.pdf

Comment: @Vanwaril  Maybe if you actually tired do your own research instead of ridiculing every post.

Comment: @Rook: I am doing my own research, but I am tired of more 'answers' that don't address what I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Vanwaril WAF's are required by the PCI-DSS,  this means that every major website that processes credit cards has a WAF.  This is for a damn good reason.

Comment: @Rook: I am simply stating that I don't believe a Web Application Firewall is enough. The problem exists because bad application code leads to query strings that have a different structure. Its simply not possible for a Firewall to identify this well, the job is more suited to 'wrappers' around the application, or like AMNESIA, static analysis.

Comment: @Rook: I'm talking about tools specifically for SQL Injection. Coverity doesn't seem to say ANYTHING in that regard.

Comment: @Rook: Good answer, except for the particular word @Vanwaril took exception to.  That is "a" way, not the "only" way.  You could for example interrupt every occurrence of every SQL keyword by inserting a zero-width space.  The user probably wouldn't ever notice, but the database wouldn't see keywords.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior with PreparedStatements in Java where you pass in each parameter makes it mostly foolproof because the framework escapes the input for you.  This doesn't prevent you from doing something like

exec spDoStuff <var>

where spDoStuff does:

exec( <var> )

But if you use normal queries it's very effective.  I don't know whether you'd consider it non-programmatic but the developer doesn't have to write the code to manage input validation themselves.

Like this:

```
int id;
String desc;
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = ? AND t2.description = ?");
// or conn.prepareStatement("EXEC spMyProcedure ?, ?");
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setString(2, desc);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
...
rs.close();
ps.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: I think you totally misread the question.  He's looking for a second layer of defense in case something was missed in the application code.